# Пасхалка веб-проекта

Tags: безопасность

Завершаем первое довольно непростое (по крайней мере для нас) веб-приложение: Yii+ExtJS. С заказчиком нашлись на фрилансе. Думаем вот о страховке, т.е. оставить например URL какой-нибудь, который в случае чего приведет к неработоспособности приложения)) Может drop таблиц по очереди, хотя на хостинге бэкапы и откатить особо не составит труда. Удаление файлов тоже самое. Может кто из фрилансеров поделится опытом как вы "подстраховываетесь"?

Comment: Одно такое срабатывание - и на карьере фрилансера можно ставить крест. Останется только подбирать мелочёвку. Подстраховываться нужно выбором заказчиков и нормальным оформлением отношений, а не такими детсадовскими способами.

Comment: угрожайте им ядерной войной как это делает Ын.

Comment: @klopp, дык как тут выбирать, когда ты лишь пару раз списывался с заказчиком? Откуда мне знать, что у него на уме. Да и нет гарантий, что после установки на его хостинге у него не возникнет желания просто "пропасть". Никто друг о друге ничего не знает и остается надеяться лишь на совесть. А почему на карьере крест? Это страховка может быть вызвана через URL только в случае неуплаты. Иначе о ней даже не узнают.

Comment: @Андрей Бакша, все капец!Не связывайся со мной! Я же Заказчик! В суд подам если дроппишь таблицы/файлы моего сайта. И копейки не дам, а Вы будете компенсировать мне зеленые капусти )))

Comment: Нет страховки лучше, чем полная оплата после предоставления доступа к приложению на СВОЁМ демонстрационном хостинге...

Comment: @morin, договорились вроде, что показываю у себя - получаю половину. Заливаю ему, он проверяет, тестит и получаю остальное. Со стороны заказчика тоже стремно заплатить всю сумму, пока у него нет работы и ничего впринципе.

Comment: Если проект на PHP, то есть решения по закрытию исходного кода, - исходники можно передать после полной оплаты.

Comment: Был один мониторинг игровой (платный!). Даже код был закодирован. Да и популярность у него была нормальная. А в папке images лежала картинка с функцией рекурсивного удаления каталогов :) Ну а что? Умные люди просто в поиске набрали пачку этих сайтов-мониторингов и привели скрипт рекурсивного удаления каталогов в действие :) А при детальном разборе движка оказалось, что пасхалок там чуть меньше, чем кода :) Не знаю, может кто-нибудь на этом форуме и узнает своё детище, мало ли :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. «сделка без риска»;
2. свой демо-сервер;
3. надпись на каждой странице или иногда, рандомно: "этот проект выполнен студией ААА в апреле 2013 и пока не оплачен клиентом Василием Пупкиным в полной мере";
4. то же, но после опр. даты просто перестаёт работать. Прятать за похожестью нуля и заглавной "О" в названиях методов, и т.п.

Понятно, что 3-4 ломается любым "другим программером", поэтому предпочтительнее 1-2.

Comment: во-во «сделка без риска» на фрилансе самое оно. частенько там дизайны заказываю.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

1. шифруем некие исходные данные (критические строки, без которых ничего не будет выполняться), с ключом.
2. ключ подгружаем со стороннего сайта (с вашего)
3. шифрованную строку в принципе тоже можно подгружать, ключ к примеру может зависеть от даты
4. декодируем при выполнении сайта
5. запускаем выполнение строки `eval('');`
6. если заказчик решает вас кидать, отключаете подгрузку ключа и критических строк

В этом случае заказчик мог бы просмотреть код, и заранее узнать какие строки загружаются с вашего сервера, но я думаю вряд ли додумается.

Comment: 1. это при каждом вызове php скрипта - запрос на удалённый сервер?  2. "додумается".

Comment: так то, между запуском на его сервере и передачей денег я думаю должно пройти не больше дня. За день проанализировать код и "додуматься" не хватит времени.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, все же можно сделать проще.

и [@IVsevolod](/users/11360/ivsevolod) дал ответ нормальный и [@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks).

Если отдать нужно исходники, то я бы сделал договор изначально что "Отдаем все вместе с кодами, или шифруем ядро и отдаем" Это как бы хорошо с одной стороны и плохо с другой.

Плюс в этом то что код знаешь только ты следовательно и заказчик от тебя просто так уйти не сможет, если захочет что-то переделать.
Минус с том что не каждый заказчик на это пойдет, ну в плане зависимости от одной фирмы.

если у тебя есть свой блог, сайт и прочее. сделай адрес для обработки запросов и/или API для получения/отдачи данных.

На разработанном сайте, создается отдельный файл, который грузится в систему в числе первых и проверяет допустим наличие в корне файла **key.php** в свою очередь этот файл можно получить только с твоего сайта, при условии того что у тебя есть таблица/файл с какими-то данными для обработки запросов от других сайтов.

Итак, делается запрос с нового сайта к твоему, они пообщались и сайт получил в ответ ключ окей, создается файл с ключем, сайт начинает работать как нужно. Если ключ не отдан, то внизу сайта появляется сообщение "Система не оплачена! Связаться с разработчиком URL сайта". И сообщение такое возможно в течении месяца, дальше система рубит ядро на исполнение и сайт ложиться.

Тут главное продумать как будут выглядеть ключи, как шифроваться будут, какого размера будут и должны содержать инфу о домене, ip или еще чего-то.

А вообще сделка без риска в руки.

Comment: Эти надписи "не оплачено" легко найти, и вычислить после чего они возникают, а значит легко подтереть.